# how to create a simple php file for generating XML result

Tags: php, xml

If I enter http://localhost/sitename?filter=city I would like to display all the cities in xml format

I would like the xml display in tag format like this

```
<city>
   <navi mumbai>
   <pune>
</city>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is sample php code , run this code with your link as **filter** as your condition

```
    Header("Content-type: text/xml"); 
    // get query string params
    $filter = $_GET['filter'];

    $xml = '';

    If ($filter == "city"){
        $xml = $xml . '<continent name="city">';
        $xml = $xml . '<city id="1">Navi Mumbai</city>';
        $xml = $xml . '<city id="2">Thane</city>';
        $xml = $xml . '<city id="3">Pune</city>';
        $xml = $xml . '</continent>';
    }else If ($filter == "country"){
        $xml = $xml . '<continent name="country">';
        $xml = $xml . '<country id="100">India</country>';
        $xml = $xml . '</continent>';
    }else If ($filter == "state"){
        $xml = $xml . '<continent name="state">';
        $xml = $xml . '<state id="300">Maharastra</state>';
        $xml = $xml . '</continent>';
    }else{
        $xml = $xml . '<continent name="none">';
        $xml = $xml . '<country id="0">no result found</country>';
        $xml = $xml . '</continent>';
    }

    // send xml to client
    echo( $xml );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From you output I assume you want something like this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET["filter"]))
    {
        $filter = $_GET["filter"];
        // create doctype
        $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");

        switch($filter)
        {
            case "city":
                // display document in browser as plain text 
                // for readability purposes
                header("Content-Type: text/plain");

                // create root element
                $root = $dom->createElement("cities");
                $dom->appendChild($root);

                // create child element
                $item = $dom->createElement("city1");
                $root->appendChild($item);

                $item = $dom->createElement("city2");
                $root->appendChild($item);
            break;

            default:
                // do something else
        }
        // save and display tree
        echo $dom->saveXML();
    }
?>
```

Please note that you cannot separate the name of an XML element with space, as you seem to have done in your example.

Comment: please be more specific , i din't even get this code to be working for me

Comment: I don’t know how much more specificity is required. I just double checked and my code correctly echoes valid XML: <?xml version="1.0"?><cities><city1/><city2/></cities>. In fact, building XML via DOM is preferred over your approach of concatenating strings which has severe performance penalties. You, in turn, did not specify the error you received. Let me know the error and I will work with you to resolve it. I hope you had a better reason for down voting my answer, looking forward to hearing it.